# FFmpeg: Connection timed out

Tags: ffmpeg

I've the following error in my FFmpeg log. It appears after 24+ hours of work.

```
rtsp://admin:passwd@myip:554/live1.sdp: Connection timed out
```

I use the following command:

```
nohup ./ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:passwd@myip:554/live1.sdp -vcodec libx264 -vb 450000 -g 60 -vprofile baseline -level 2.1 -acodec aac -ab 64000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -strict experimental -f mpegts udp://serverip:10013?pkt_size=1316 &
```

Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very common issue with all of the "external" input sources, for example with network inputs, which can stop for a while due to network connectivity issues. 
It seems that the -shortest output option is the most viable option in this case - and you have a cronjob that constantly checks it process died and restarts if required.

Hopefully some better option is there, but after an extensive search I was unable to find it.

Regards.